# res.redirect is not a function - express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to Express.js and am trying to create a URL shortener.

When the user naviagtes to domain.com/r/ I query the DB for the param and get the actual URL.

I use res.redirect to try to redirect to their stored URL but it fails with 'res.redirect is not a function'.

Please see the snippet below:

```
router.get('/r/:shortUrl', function(req, res) {

  connectDatabase.then(
    checkDatabase(req.params.shortUrl)
      .then( res => {
        console.log('checkdatdabase res => ' + res); //res = 'https://www.google.com'
        res.redirect(res); //TypeError: res.redirect is not a function
      })
      .catch(e => {
        //executed due to above error
        console.error(e);
        res.redirect(307, '/home');
      })
  )
});
```

Any advice would be much appreciated as this is a learning project for me.

Comment: You're redeclaring res in: `checkDatabase(req.params.shortUrl).then(res=> {})`, change the name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

datdabaseRes and res should be different variable name. Otherwise res has the respose object of database connection in the scope you are trying to use it.

```js
   

router.get('/r/:shortUrl', function(req, res) {
  connectDatabase.then(
    checkDatabase(req.params.shortUrl)
      .then( datdabaseRes => {
        console.log('checkdatdabase res => ' + datdabaseRes); //res = 'https://www.google.com'
        res.redirect(datdabaseRes); //TypeError: res.redirect is not a function
      })
      .catch(e => {
        //executed due to above error
        console.error(e);
        res.redirect(307, '/home');
      })
  )
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two variables named `res`.

One, passed to the callback you pass to `get()` is a response object which has a `redirect` method.

The other is the resolved value of `checkDatabase` and is not a response object.

The latter has [shadowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the former so you can't access it any more.

Use unique names for your variables to avoid this problem.

---

I recommend using a linter. ESLint can catch this kind of problem with the [no-shadow rule](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-shadow).